# Un-deploy hosted engine from node before minor upgrade?

Tags: ovirt

A node in our ovirt cluster shows an available upgrade. The node has the hosted engine deployed on it, but it is currently served on another node. Do I need to un-deploy the hosted engine first before making a minor upgrade ?

Currently for every upgrade I am moving the node to maintenance and then I will un-deploy the hosted engine. After that the node is active again and I have to put it into maintenance again before starting the upgrade. After the upgrade the node is active again, so it has to be put into maintenance again and then deploy the hosted engine once again.

That's a lot of steps to take for an upgrade. Can I skip the un-deployment of the hosted engine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to un-deploy your node from Hosted Engine, just put one node per time in maintenance and perform the minor upgrade. I try to summarize the whole process, gleaning information from the official documentation.

1. Put the fist node in Global Maintenance from either the Administration Portal:

   > - Click **Compute** → **Hosts** and select a self-hosted engine node.
   > - Click **Management** → **Maintenance**. The local maintenance mode is automatically triggered for that node.

   or from the command line:
   `# hosted-engine --set-maintenance --mode=local`
2. If migration is enabled at cluster level, wait for the VMs to be migrated to another node in the cluster.
3. Update the node from either the Administration Portal:

   > - Click **Compute** → **Hosts** and select the node to be updated.
   > - Click **Installation** → **Check for Upgrade** to open the **Upgrade Host**
   >     confirmation window.
   > - Click **OK** to begin the upgrade check.
   > - To upgrade the host, click **Installation** → **Upgrade** to open the **Upgrade Host** confirmation window.
   > - Click **OK** to update the host. After the upgrade, the host is restarted.

   or from the command line:
   `# yum update`
   `# systemctl reboot`
4. After the node has been rebooted, disable the Maintenance:

   > - Click **Compute** → **Hosts** and select the self-hosted engine node.
   > - Click **Management** → **Activate**.

   or from the command line:
   `# hosted-engine --set-maintenance --mode=none`
5. Repeat the update procedure for each node in the environment.